# Three planes in general position, one point in each, construct sections

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

I have three planes in general position, and in each plane an
arbitrary point is selected : this gives us three points $R,S,T$.
Is it possible to construct the intersection lines of the $(RST)$
plane with each of the original planes using only a straightedge 
(so, we can only draw parallels and locate intersection points of two
secant lines)?

[image]

One could formalize the problem as follows : we have a set $\cal S$ of lines and points, defined as the smallest set containing $R,S,T$ and the three intersection lines of the original planes, and closed with respect to line intersection (if two secant lines $D,D' \in {\cal S}$, then the intersection point $D\cap D'$ is in $\cal S$) and parallel straight lines (if $D\in S$ and $p\in S$ then the parallel to $D$ passing by $p$ is in $\cal S$). The question can then be restated as, does $\cal S$ contain the intersection lines of $(RST)$ with the original planes.

Comment: How are the planes given? Can we find the intersection point of a line an a plane?

Comment: @MichaelBiro No, we can't "find the intersection point of an arbitrary line and an arbitrary plane" that would make the problem trivial. We are however originally given the three intersection lines of the three original planes.

Comment: How do you use a straightedge in 3D space?

Comment: @RoryDaulton It should be clear that we are making a 2D drawing to represent a 3D reality, with the usual conventions. Also, the last paragraph in the OP clarifies this.

Comment: @RoryDaulton By the way, if you don't like 3D space the original question is clearly equivalent to a similar question in the 2D plane (consider the set $\cal S$ in a plane instead of in the 3D space).

Comment: May we use a compass and a 1 unit line segment too?

Comment: @RicardoCruz No you can't use a compass (that would make an interesting other problem though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is YES (and I got it from a MO user in a comment shortly after having copied this question to MO ; the MO version is now deleted as it
is not research-level).

Let us denote the $(RST)$ plane by $\Pi$.
Let us perturbate the initial problem slightly, replacing
$R$ with a point $R'$ on one of the lines defining the "yellow" 
plane containing $R$.

Then the intersection of $\Pi'=(R'ST)$ with our initial 
three "coloured" planes is easy to construct, as shown below :

[image]

Next, notice that the intersection point of $(ST)$
and $(R'H)$ (let us call it $D$) is remarkable in that
he is on $\Pi$, $\Pi'$ and the "yellow" plane all at once :

[image]

It follows that the intersection of $\Pi$ with the yellow plane
is simply $(DR)$. The other intersections are constructed
similarly.